# Scrapy excluding blank spaces

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I have tried scrape a link(https://www.century21.com/real-estate/rock-spring-ga/LCGAROCKSPRING/). I wanted to extract "beds" data from that. since there are some empty details for some houses in that, only few "beds" details are extracted. But i want to have the details for all. If not there, then it should show "NaN" or something. Another problem is that i have inspected this tag:

```html
<div class="property-beds">
            <strong>2</strong> beds
         </div>
```

i used the xpath command to extract "2 beds". Only "beds" is displayed nOT "2 beds". So i used "|" to unify the 2 elements.

```
response.xpath('//div[@class="property-beds"]/strong/text() | //div[@class="property-beds"]/text()']
```

this got me the correct output but the problem is it is showing result in 2 seperate lines(2 in one line and beds in another line).how to display in single line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `string()` on the parent element to extract the text of the element and all child nodes:

```
In [10]: root.xpath('string(//div[@class="property-beds"])')
Out[10]: '2 beds'
```

If you have more than one element, you'll have to iterate through the elements matched by `//div[@class="property-beds"]` and then do `elem.xpath('string()')`.

Comment: Can u explain the second part plz. Iterating the command for more than 1 element case.

Comment: @AkhilReddy: `string()` only works on the first element in the set. You'll have to do `for elem in response.xpath('//div[@class="property-beds"]'): print(elem.xpath('string()').extract())`.

Answer (score 0):

Use string() method.`root.xpath('string(//div[@class="property-beds"])')`